# How to get the intersection of two terms both from different custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, get-posts

I have a  custom post type `listing`

Then there are two custom taxonomies

1. job_listing_region
2. job_listing_category

On home page i have links to `job_listing_category` like `shop`,`eat`,`stay` etc.

and job listing region like himalyan  and non-himalyan.

there are two tabs for himalyan and non-himalyan.

Under each tab there are  i links to `job_listing_category` like `shop`,`eat`,`stay` etc.

From there are i want a link to archive page of each of these `job_listing_category`.

Like if person click on shop under himalyan category then it should get me to archive page 
where there are posts from  `shop` as well as `himalyan`

[image]
How do i acheive this , i have no idea . Please help / give som directions how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

The custom query to get custom post type posts filtered by 2 different terms from 2 different taxonomies will be:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_region',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'himalyan', // this can be an array of terms also
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'shop', // this can be an array of terms also
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Adjust `tax_query` values to your needs, e.g. pass 'terms' via $variable you get from URL, for example:

```
$region = get_query_var('job_listing_region');
$args = array(
    ...
    'terms' => $region;
    ...
);
```

Also, read through [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) docs, you should make use of custom post type / custom taxonomy templates, and use `pre_get_posts` filter to adjust your queries.

Comment: thanks for sharing your view. But the first query you shared , it will give me the posts as i want. But not a link to archive page where this query will display the posts . For this do achieve i need to pass variables to the archive page according to on which link i click. And how do i do that.. i have no idea for now

Comment: That's why I added a link to template hierarchy and mentioned pre_get_posts filter. You can also create a custom template, add some custom rewrite rules. Once you have a working page which uses your custom query and gets proper results, building custom links to this page(s) is not a problem. I'll give you the code a bit later, when I have more time. Meanwhile, check the docs and get familiar with WP_Query, Template Hierarchy, Rewrite Rules, some filters - pre_get_posts, parse_query, template_include. This will help you to understand the code I'll post.

Comment: okay going to try that